# Gson JsonObject global variable

Tags: java, json, gson

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gson JsonObject global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499846/gson-jsonobject-global-variable)

I'm using Gson API and created a class like:

```
public class Person
{
   private String name;
   private JsonObject someInfo;

   public Person(String name, String someInfo)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.someInfo = someInfoM
   }
}
```

When I serealize an instance of this class using:

```
Person person = new Person("Charles", "{\"key1\":\"value1\"}");
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(person);
```

I get the info inside a members properties:

```
{"members":"{"name":"Charles",{"key1","value1"}}"}
```

I've noticed that If I declare the Person's class someInfo global variable as JsonElement instead of JsonObject the info is displayed correctly.

Is there any way to serealize the information using JsonObject?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to a [Gson 2.2](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list). Gson has only supported serializing JsonObject etc. since 2.0.