# Gson JsonObject global variable

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using Gson API and created a class like:

```
public class Person
{
   private String name;
   private JsonObject someInfo;

   public Person()
   {
   }
}
```

When I serealize an instance of this class using:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.name = "Charles"
person.someInfo = new JsonObject();
person.someInfo.addProperty("key1","value1");
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(person);
```

I get the info inside a members properties:

```
{"members":{"name":"Charles","someInfo":{"key1":"value1"}}}
```

I've noticed that if I declare the Person's class someInfo global variable as JsonElement instead of JsonObject the info is displayed correctly.

Is there any way to serealize the information using JsonObject?

What I expect is:

```
{"name":"Charles","someInfo":{"key1":"value1"}}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work. You cannot assign a String to a JsonObject!

Comment: Also show us what you would expect. We don't know what it is _the info is displayed correctly._

Comment: Sorry I wrote this code right here in a rush... already edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Map for your someInfo:

```
public class Person
{
   private String name;
   private Map<Object, Object> someInfo;

   public Person()
   {
   }

}

Person person = new Person();
person.name = "Charles";
person.someInfo = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
person.someInfo.put("key1","value1");
```

Although it would be better to use proper getters/setters to access `Person` variables.

Comment: That's what I was using before... What I would really like to do is use Gson's classes

Comment: @RedEagle Why would you want to replace it with JSonObject/JsonElement/JSonArray, etc...? These are low-level objects which you should not have to manipulate unless you are writing TypeAdapters. Using a Map is the correct way to go if you don't know in advance the structure of your elements.

Comment: I'm starting to think you're right since although GSON is very powerfull, it's base classes lack some capabilities offered by Map and List (as a replacement of JsonArray)

Comment: @RedEagle If you think in terms of "Model", you would want your model to be independent of your serialization mechanisms. If tomorrow you were to find out that XML is better than JSON (I am not saying it is!), you would have to change your model if you used JSON-objects, while if you used List and Map's you wouldn't need to.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem using Gson 2.2.2.

When I upgraded to Gson 2.2.3, I got the expected JSON when I serialized JsonObject.